# Isometric Spaces

Tags: analysis

The space A is said to be isometric with the space B if there exists a bijective isometry of A onto B. So, the spaces A and B are called isometric spaces.
Does isometric spaces have the same properties like dense, completeness, compactness,...etc

Comment: Yes they do have all the properties same. In the case of isometry the elements of A and B are just renamed with no properties altered.

Answer (score 1):

An isometry is actually just a special form of a topological homeomorphism, hence all properties that are conserved under homeomorphisms (called topological properties) are also conserved under isometries. A list of commonly used topological properties can be found on:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_property